# How to backup source repository and zip destination folders?

Tags: backup, backup-strategies

All sources are on windows OS, and destination backup is on Unix system (we are using Samba).

My source repository is similar to :

```
-Repository
--Folder1
---Files
--Folder2
---Files
etc...
```

I would like to get a destination similar to :

```
-Repository
--Folder1.zip
--Folder2.zip
etc...
```

After first backup, I only backup files that have changed since the last backup. (or backup if new folders/files have been created).

Is someone know a tool or a script for my backup needs? Can we do that with Robocopy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may install cygwin on your Windows machine, and use simple sh script, like the following one:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( ls ); do
        tar czf $i.tar.gz $i
done

# specify your destination here:
rsync *.tar.gz /tmp
rm *.tar.gz
```

BTW, that's not the most straightforward way, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to forget about the zipping part, I would advise backuppc on the Unix system and [rsync (win32 port)](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=34854) / or samba config on the Windows system

see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupPC and http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/ for more infos

Comment: No, I can't forget the zipping part. Actually, we have 20TB to backup.

Comment: There is compression in backuppc, you should give it a shot (see http://goo.gl/GkOR)